# Flutter: How to change focus to another widget when a certain key is pressed on physical keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I'm developing a desktop app on Windows and am trying to move focus to a Textfield when the ENTER key is pressed on another textfield.
I'm able to detect the key has been pressed using `RawKeyboardListener` but focus isnt changed to the new field. How can I get this working?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late FocusNode _txtNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _txtNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _txtNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
              height: 400,
              width: 500,
              color: Colors.grey[350],
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      height: 100,
                      child: RawKeyboardListener(
                        focusNode: FocusNode(),
                          onKey: (event){
                          if (event.toString().contains('RawKeyDownEvent') && event.toString().contains('Enter')) {
                            print("pressed ENTER");
                            _txtNode.requestFocus();
                          }
                          },
                          child: TextField(readOnly: true,))
                  ),
                  TextField(
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    focusNode: _txtNode,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved your use case by just modified your code snippets. Please check the below code snippets. `FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus()` is used to move the focus to the next. If you want to move a focus to a specific widget. you just call that `focusNode.requestFocus()`.

```dart
class FocusDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FocusDemoState createState() => _FocusDemoState();
}

class _FocusDemoState extends State<FocusDemo> {
  late FocusNode _txtNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _txtNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _txtNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Focus(
          focusNode: _txtNode,
          onKey: (focusNode, event) {
            if (event.runtimeType == RawKeyUpEvent &&
                event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
              focusNode.nextFocus();
              return KeyEventResult.handled;
            }
            return KeyEventResult.ignored;
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 400,
            width: 500,
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've retested and it doesnt seem to be working. Focus is not being set

Comment: Okay brother, I will check and revert back.

Comment: @West, Can you please check the current code snippets?

Comment: Screen doesnt render no more I got an error `No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FocusDemo file:///C:/Users/Public/Android/Projects/tests/lib/main.dart:5:10` Are you testing the code before posting and does it work on your end?

Comment: Yes I ensured. Please wrap `MaterialApp` widget to the parent of `Scaffold` widget and check?

Comment: Sure that makes it render again. But seems now none of the TextFields can be typed into

Comment: Thanks I've edited your answer so that it allows the TextFields to be edited. I'll accept it now:)

Comment: I've heard about issues with checking `event.runtimeType` in production so I instead use `if (event.toString().contains('RawKeyDownEvent') && event.toString().contains('Enter')) {}`